# How to access elements of json in Angular 2

Tags: json, angular

when I did

```
loadPeople(){

    this.myService.load().then(data => {
            this.people = data;
            alert(this.people);
        });
    }
```

it alerts json as :

```
 {
"status": "true",
"statusCode": 200,
"response": [{
    "user_id": "92",
    "firstname": "joy",
    "lastname": "Panchal",
    "email": "joy@gmail.com",
    "password": "7Y7+K0vZIVWPDUQH++Iu+/+tMZ",
    "user_type_id": "1"
}, {
    "user_id": "89",
    "firstname": "mark",
    "lastname": "haris",
    "email": "mark@gmail.com",
    "password": "4JICqnTkR8ysTI+nQQ+rpfAf7e",
    "user_type_id": "1"
}]
```

}

now i am trying to access "response" by

```
loadPeople(){

this.myService.load().then(data => {
        this.people = data.response;
        alert(this.people);
    });
}
```

but it alerts as "undefined" .

can anyone tell where i am missing ??

Comment: Should work perfectly fine. http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/10046/

Comment: yes it should , but dont know what went wrong . alert still saying "undefined"

Comment: probably this.people is not yet filled.

Comment: thanks matheno , i will prefer your suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can access like this. please try.

```
`loadPeople(){
  this.myService.load().then(data => {
    this.people = JSON.parse(data.response);
    alert(this.people);
});
```

}`

Answer (score 0):

you need parse JSON first:

```
this.myService.load().then(data => {
    let res = JSON.parse(data);
    this.people = res.response;
    alert(this.people);
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, it says "  Property 'response' does not exist on type 'string'. " as it is JSON element.

Comment: could you console.log your `data` variable

Comment: yes, console.log it shawing when i am trying with "  this.people = data " ,
not happening the same for "  this.people = data.response "

Comment: your `data` is object or json string

Comment: its JSON stirng

Comment: so you need convert from JSON to js Object first